# Is there a WhosHere-style (location-based) social networking chat app for Android?

Tags: applications, geolocation, chat

I like the WhosHere app for Apple iPhone iOS. Is there a similar social networking/chat app that uses location / gps to find people to chat or network with for Android?

Here's some more info on the application: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whoshere/id284973016

[image: who's here app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I could find so far:

- [FlirtMaps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.flirtmaps.android&feature=search_result), the first geo-aware mobile dating apps to find dates!
  You are either very smart or very lucky! You’ve just found FlirtMaps, the first geo-aware mobile dating app that lets you find your next date right in the neighborhood... or around the world!
- [Skout](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skout.android) for flirting, dating, friendship and love! Chat and browse photos for FREE! Use SKOUT to flirt, play, party, find a date or new friends. At SKOUT we take your safety and privacy very seriously. No one can figure out your exact whereabouts.
- [I'm Here Plus](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.paulxiong.imhereplus) allows you to use SMS text messaging to check the status and GPS location of any person on your contact list, as long as they have "Im Here Plus" installed as well. You may also choose to send others your current location via SMS, whether with just your GPS address or with an edited personalized location.
- If you root your android phone and enable wifi tethering, you could use your ipod touch tethered through the droid and still use whosHere

I haven't tested any of these out. If you can comment with which of these you prefer, that would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[SayHi](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.unearby.sayhi) seems to replicate WhosHere. The plus side of it is that it has a map function so you're able to see how many users are currently online. The downside of the app is that it uses your exact GPS location which might not go down with some users (ie. using the app at home/office).

Also, there are point rewards that you get for completing your profile and using the app frequently. You can use these points to contacting users that have a hot status or use to send gifts - you have the option to buy points but if you use it enough then put that credit card away :)